# Jenkins with AWS Fargate using ECS-Fargate plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to create a Jenkins/Fargate CI-CD workflow ( via the ECS-Fargate plugin). So jenkins would make use of Fargate tasks to do its work.

Two of the stages that i'm trying as part of the workflow:

1. Docker Build

   How can we build or create a docker image out of a docker file on Fargate?
2. Docker Image scan

   How and what tools can we use to scan and run the docker image scan stage on Fargate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/building-container-images-on-amazon-ecs-on-aws-fargate/) for #1.

As per #2, [Amazon ECR supports image scans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/image-scanning.html) so you can leverage that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use kaniko for building image in fargate container. You can check this github repository [Jenkins agent docker kaniko](https://github.com/Dwolla/jenkins-agent-docker-kaniko).